# set back button title text in iOS Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, back-button

I want to set the BackButton Title text to ""(means empty). I am using below code to set the Title but it is not working.

**Try 1 :**

```
this.NavigationItem.BackBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem("", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, null);
```

**Try 2 :**

```
this.NavigationItem.BackBarButtonItem.Title = "";
```

it is give the `object is not set to instance`.

Is there any way to set the Back button title null in iOS.

Any Help Will be Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the workaround I do simple trick.

before going to new UIViewController set the Title to `""`. and on Back button press when you come to ViewController inside the `ViewDidAppear`method set the Title again.

Answer (score 0):

Back Title depends on Title property of ViewController .

and it could be set as below , here vc is the instance of controller which is pushed inside UINavigationController .

```
vc.NavigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItem (new UIBarButtonItem(
UIImage.FromFile("29_icon.png"), UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, (sender, args) => {
    NavigationController.PopViewControllerAnimated(true);
}), true);
```

[https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/navigation_controller/change_the_back_button/](http://Refer%20this%20for%20detail)

Above link explains in details .
Let me know after this also if you find problem doing it .

Answer (score 0):

Back button by default use title from previous view controller. So you need to change title of previous of veiw controller to change back button title.

To hide title, you can use  [SetBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIBarButtonItem.SetBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment/p/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIOffset/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIBarMetrics/) to set offset of Title and move title to invisible area of button by passing (-80,-80) in offset.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

this.NavigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItem(new UIBarButtonItem("text", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain , (sender, args) => { }), true);

Answer (score 0):

You can set it like this in the parent controller before doing PushViewController

this.NavigationItem.BackBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem("", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, null);